# AEM Java - Create Collection - how to create sling:members?

Tags: java, aem

I was able to create a new collection with the following:

```
Resource resource = resourceResolver.resolve(DEFAULT_BASE_JCR_PATH+"/m/mKS6YofYC4-opD0lu2gc");

ResourceCollectionManager managerCollection = resourceResolver.adaptTo(ResourceCollectionManager.class);
ResourceCollection collection = managerCollection.createCollection(resource, collectionName);
```

What is the best way of creating the sling:members and adding resources?

Answer (score 0):

I will was able to figure this out:
The input(collectionMember) is from a text area:

/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/brand/brand_1_c02.jpg,/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/brand/brand_3a_ambassdors_c03.png,
/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/brand/brand_3b_1_c05.jpg

```
Resource resourcesResource =   resourceResolver.resolve(DEFAULT_BASE_JCR_PATH+"/"+session.getUserID()+"/"+collectionName+"/sling:members");
String[] resources = collectionMember.split(",");

        for (String img : resources) {
            String imgName = img.substring(img.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, img.length());
            Node nodeMember = resourcesResource.adaptTo(Node.class);;
            Node mem = nodeMember.addNode(imgName, "nt:unstructured");
            setBasicProp(mem);
            mem.setProperty("sling:resource", img);
        }


outside of method.....
private void setBasicProp(Node node) throws Exception {
            Calendar lastModified = Calendar.getInstance();
            String user = node.getSession().getUserID();

            node.setProperty("jcr:createdBy", user);
            node.setProperty("jcr:lastModifiedBy", user);
            node.setProperty("jcr:lastModified", lastModified);
            node.setProperty("jcr:created", lastModified);
            node.setProperty("jcr:description", node.getName());
}
```